# Pandas - Groupby and Standardize

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to tackle this for quite some time, but haven't been able to get a pythonic way around it by using the built-in `groupby` and `transform` methods from pandas.

The goal is to group the data by columns `ex_date` and `id`, then within the groups identified, standardize the column called `ref_value_1` against the value found in the row where `df['calc_date'] == df['ex_date']`

Here's a sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'calc_date': ['1/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '1/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '1/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '1/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021'], 'ex_date': ['2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021'], 'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'ref_value_1': [1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0, 40.0, 60.0, 75.0, 100.0, 120.0], 'bins': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
```

which looks like:

| calc_date | ex_date | id | ref_value_1 | bins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 1.5 | 1 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 4.5 | 1 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 15 | 1 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 15 | 2 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 40 | 2 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 60 | 2 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 75 | 3 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 100 | 3 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 120 | 3 |

And expected output:

| calc_date | ex_date | id | ref_value_1 | bins | standardized_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 1.5 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 4.5 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 15 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 15 | 2 | 0.375 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 40 | 2 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3 | 60 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 75 | 3 | 0.75 |
| 2/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 100 | 3 | 1 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 4 | 120 | 3 | 1.2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask the non matching values and fill per group using `groupby`+`transform` to get the reference. Then simply divide your data with the reference.

```
ref = df['ref_value_1'].where(df['calc_date'].eq(df['ex_date'])).groupby(df['id']).transform('first')

df['standardized_val'] = df['ref_value_1'].div(ref)
```

Output:

```
   calc_date   ex_date  id  ref_value_1  bins  standardized_val
0   1/1/2021  2/1/2021   1          1.5     1             0.500
1   2/1/2021  2/1/2021   1          3.0     1             1.000
2   3/1/2021  2/1/2021   1          4.5     1             1.500
3   1/1/2021  2/1/2021   2          5.0     1             0.500
4   2/1/2021  2/1/2021   2         10.0     1             1.000
5   3/1/2021  2/1/2021   2         15.0     1             1.500
6   1/1/2021  2/1/2021   3         15.0     2             0.375
7   2/1/2021  2/1/2021   3         40.0     2             1.000
8   3/1/2021  2/1/2021   3         60.0     2             1.500
9   1/1/2021  2/1/2021   4         75.0     3             0.750
10  2/1/2021  2/1/2021   4        100.0     3             1.000
11  3/1/2021  2/1/2021   4        120.0     3             1.200
```

Comment: Hey thanks - this worked great and was super quick. Just some modifications for the final code and a couple of questions:

```
 ref = df['ref_value_1'].where(df['calc_date']==df['ex_date']).groupby([df['ex_date'], df['id']]).transform('first')

df['standardized_val'] = df['ref_value_1'].div(ref)
```

1. Are there advantages of using .eq() over ==?
2. The usage of a dataframe column is new to me, I tried use ['ex_date', id'] and it didn't work. Could you elaborate a little on that? I'm going to read the documentation right after this, but thought it might be useful for anyone else.

Comment: @Winsor-Mavis 1- here this is exactly the same. With 2D data, `eq` is useful when you want to change the axis on which to perform the comparison. 2- sorry but I don't understand the question, what exactly have you tried and what didn't work? Maybe it would be worth opening a new question on that with all the details ;)

Comment: Will do, thanks!